# How to Adding suview to the UIImagePickerViewController in ipad

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.2

I need to add two button in the UIImagePickerViewController for the iPad. I don't know how to increase the size of the UIPopOverViewController if it is possible I will add them as a subview. Please help on this regard, is there any better ideas to add a subview to the UIImagePickerViewController?.

Thanks in Advance,
Sekhar Bethalam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking this is one of those shrink wrapped objects that are provided to be used as is and you shouldn't be trying to change the look and feel. Any hackiness to with getting hold of the pickers internal methods would render your app unsubmitable.

However have you tried taking the view object out of the picker view controller and placing it in your own view hierachy?

You can change the pop-over content size with the `popoverContentSize` method of `UIPopoverController`

Comment: No, I need it for the inbuilt UIImagePickerViewController. Thanks for your reply